# Does Fortran resolve optional arguments and present statements during compile-time?

Tags: runtime, fortran, fortran90, compile-time, option-type

After a search without any result I want to ask you a question regarding subroutines containing optional arguments and how they are treated by the compiler (run time/compile time). Consider the following example program.

```
  module CONTAINS_ABC

  contains

  subroutine ABC( a, b, c)

  implicit none

  real, intent(in)           :: a
  real, intent(in), optional :: b, c

  if( present(b) )then ! PATH_B
     write(*,*) 'Provide c'
  else if( present(c) )then "! PATH_C
     write(*,*) 'Provide b'
  end if

  ! Do all the computations with a, b and c 

  end subroutine ABC

  end module CONTAINS_ABC


  program CALL_ABC

  use CONTAINS_ABC

  real :: aa, bb, cc


  call ABC( a = aa, b=bb )

  call ABC( a = aa, c=cc )


  end program CALL_ABC
```

I wonder how the compiler treats subroutines with optional arguments in terms of `optimization`. Does the compiler produce implicitly two interfaces for the subroutine **FCN** and chooses then the right one during compile time in the main program? Furthermore, is the **present(b)/present(c)** statement evaluated at runtime or during compile time? 
In case I understand things right, the compiler might know that the first call to ABC leads to the path **B**, while the second call to **ABC** must lead to path **C**.
I ask this question, since I have a subroutine that is called million-million of times.

I want to avoid that during runtime the decision is made wether to go along **path B** or **path C**. It would be possible of course two write simply two subroutines, however, this would produce a lot of additional lines that would actually do the same thing.

Thank you all in advance for your help!

Comment: This seems to me like a micro-optimization that would be unlikely to save significant CPU run time and would not be worth the tradeoff in less maintainable code.  Just guessing.  Have you profiled your code to see where the CPU consumption is?

Comment: I haven't profiled the code yet, however, you might be right with your guess. I just thought to ask in advance …

Answer (score 7):

The Fortran standards are silent on pretty much every aspect of the implementation of the language other than the syntax and semantics.  For example, people often think that Fortran passes arguments by reference but the standard only requires that programs behave as if arguments are passed by reference.  Implementers are free to use *pass-by-pixies* if they wish and if they can thereby produce a convincing simulation of pass by reference.

That's just a long-winded introduction to telling you that how a particular compiler implements a language feature is, in general, compiler-specific.  Implementation details are also know to vary from version to version of the same compiler.

I think that you are wrong to think that the presence of an optional argument will be checked at compile-time even if it is provable that it could be -- I just don't think that that is something that the current crop of compilers do.  I expect the compiler to generate a single  implementation of the subroutine with optional arguments.  It does, after all, rest with the programmer to ensure that a procedure does not attempt to process absent optional arguments.

If you, the programmer, know that a procedure will be executed many times and if you suspect that different implementations, one with argument `b` and without `c`, one *vice-versa*, then it's on you to determine if separate implementations will be faster than one implementation with optional arguments.  If you are concerned about code duplication you could always have yet a third procedure to implement the common code, and call it from both variants.

Equally, it is on you to inspect the assembler generated by your compiler to see just what your compiler (version) does with the variations in code that you write.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation. Your comment and especially the code example helped me a lot to understand how present and optional statements are treated. You are right that it is on me to make the right decision, furthermore, I will think about the 'third procedure' way that might solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I will add an example. This is what `gfortran-4.8` does with your code with `-Ofast` (`-fdump-tree-optimized`). There is only one copy of the subroutine and the `if (present())` calls are changed to `if (b_1(D) != 0B)`. Maybe some smaller subroutine would be inlined. Then I would expect such an optimization to kick in, but not here.

```
;; Function abc (__contains_abc_MOD_abc, funcdef_no=0, decl_uid=1875, cgraph_uid=0)

abc (real(kind=4) & restrict a, real(kind=4) * b, real(kind=4) * c)
{
  struct __st_parameter_dt dt_parm.1;
  struct __st_parameter_dt dt_parm.0;

  <bb 2>:
  if (b_1(D) != 0B)
    goto <bb 3>;
  else
    goto <bb 4>;

  <bb 3>:
  dt_parm.0.common.filename = &"opt.f90"[1]{lb: 1 sz: 1};
  dt_parm.0.common.line = 13;
  dt_parm.0.common.flags = 128;
  dt_parm.0.common.unit = 6;
  _gfortran_st_write (&dt_parm.0);
  _gfortran_transfer_character_write (&dt_parm.0, &"Provide c"[1]{lb: 1 sz: 1}, 9);
  _gfortran_st_write_done (&dt_parm.0);
  dt_parm.0 ={v} {CLOBBER};
  goto <bb 6>;

  <bb 4>:
  if (c_11(D) != 0B)
    goto <bb 5>;
  else
    goto <bb 6>;

  <bb 5>:
  dt_parm.1.common.filename = &"opt.f90"[1]{lb: 1 sz: 1};
  dt_parm.1.common.line = 15;
  dt_parm.1.common.flags = 128;
  dt_parm.1.common.unit = 6;
  _gfortran_st_write (&dt_parm.1);
  _gfortran_transfer_character_write (&dt_parm.1, &"Provide b"[1]{lb: 1 sz: 1}, 9);
  _gfortran_st_write_done (&dt_parm.1);
  dt_parm.1 ={v} {CLOBBER};

  <bb 6>:
  return;

}



;; Function main (main, funcdef_no=2, decl_uid=1889, cgraph_uid=2) (executed once)

main (integer(kind=4) argc, character(kind=1) * * argv)
{
  real(kind=4) aa;
  real(kind=4) bb;
  real(kind=4) cc;
  static integer(kind=4) options.2[7] = {68, 1023, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0};

  <bb 2>:
  _gfortran_set_args (argc_2(D), argv_3(D));
  _gfortran_set_options (7, &options.2[0]);
  abc (&aa, &bb, 0B);
  abc (&aa, 0B, &cc);
  aa ={v} {CLOBBER};
  bb ={v} {CLOBBER};
  cc ={v} {CLOBBER};
  return 0;

}
```

I checked this is also the case for the final assembly, but it is much more clearly visible here in GIMPLE.